# Scala create a List with Future in a for loop and check the result of each Future

Tags: scala, future

I need to process list of entry in parallel and validate the results. Can anybody help me in achieving this in Scala

it is something like below,

```
FileList = List { "/temp/File1", "/temp/File2","/temp/File3","/temp/File4"........}

for( file <- FileList){
  Future { getRecCount(file) } // Need to create a List with all Futures
}
```

Now i need to check the result of all Futures till it completes

getRecCount - will calculate the record count and writes into an file

Comment: Have you looked at `Future.traverse`?

Comment: That's not how you declare a `List`. Use parentheses, not braces. (You can only swap parentheses for braces when the function takes a single argument.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just interested in Exception, you can wrap the body of Future in [Try](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/util/Try.html) and use [Future.traverse](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#traverse[A,B,M[X]<:TraversableOnce[X]](in:M[A])(fn:A=>scala.concurrent.Future[B])(implicitcbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[M[A],B,M[B]],implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[M[B]]) as @adrice727 mentioned for paralles files processing:

```
// Sequence of files for processing
val files = Seq[String]("/tmp/1.txt", "/tmp/2.txt", "/tmp/3.txt", "/tmp/4.txt",
  "/tmp/5.txt", "/tmp/6.txt")

def fileHandler(path: String): String = {
  val idx = files.indexOf(path)
  // Throw exception for each second file
  if (idx % 2 == 0) throw new Exception(s"Unable to hande $path")
  else path
}

val futures: Future[Seq[Try[String]]] = Future.traverse(files){ path =>
  Future {
    // Wrap it by Try
    Try {
      // Each file handler
      fileHandler(path)
    }
  }
}

futures.map { seq =>
  seq.map {
    case Success(s) => println(s"Result: $s")
    case Failure(ex) => println(s"Exception: ${ex.getMessage}")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - This is how i implemented

val tobeProcesssed : Seq[String] =  Seq("FileName1", "FileName2", "FileName3,"FileName4)    //  Created a Seq with File Names

```
    val latch = new CDL(tobeProcesssed.size)
      val trackFutures: Future[Seq[Try[Boolean]]] = Future.traverse(tobeProcesssed.seq) { fileNm =>
        Future {
          LOG.info("In the Futures Loop for {}", fileNm)
          Try {
                    doProcessing(fileNm)
          }
        }
      }

      trackFutures.map { seq =>
        seq.map {
          case Success(state) => {
            if (state) {
              LOG.info("On Sucess - {} - {}", latch.getCount, state)
              return = 0
              latch.countDown()

            } else {
              LOG.error("Failed - {} - {}", latch.getCount, state)
              while (latch.getCount > 0) {
                return  = 1
                latch.countDown()
              }
            }

          }
          case Failure(exception) => {
            LOG.error("Versioning Failed -{} - {}", latch.countDown(), exception)
            while (latch.getCount > 0) {
              return = = 1
              latch.countDown()
            }
          }
        }
      }
      latch.await()
```